# Как правильно захостить mern-stack приложение

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, хостинг

Допустим, при локальной разработке сервер запускается на `localhost:5000`, а клиент на `localhost:3000`.

(Как на сервере, так и на клиенте разная маршрутизация)

Как правильно захостить такое приложение. Пока у меня в голове только одна мысль - поместить все это на 2 разных хоста, но мне не кажется, что это правильное решение.

Comment: клиент на localhost:3000 - обычно же используется в дев режиме, для hot-reload. А в прод-режиме, сервер же должен отдавать готовый html. Другими словами, 2-й сервер, который будет крутится на 3000-порту, совсем не нужен

Comment: @Дмытрык, вопрос по реализации: mern представляется вроде как 3 независимых объекта: фронтенд, бекэнд и бд. Не совсем понятно, как я должен отдавать фронтенд с бекэнда.

Comment: Я с реактом не работал. Но по аналогии со Vue - Вы должны сбилдить продакшшн версию фронтенда. И с помощью сервера, отдавать получившийся контент

Comment: К тому же, Вы, скорее всего,все равно будете использовать прокси-сервер, типа Nginx. Поэтому отдача статики будет на его плечах